# Background Image won't center in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm making a site with a background image on every page. The image is centered in Chrome, Safari, Firefox... But it won't center in IE 9 (not sure about the other versions of IE).

Here's the CSS:

```
#page {
    background-image: url(images/mountain2.jpg);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #6C86FF;
    width:1292;
    height:972;
}
```

(#page, is the div tag for the entire site.)

Help, is very much appreciated. =)

Comment: Remember to add units (unless the value is `0`). Your `width` and `height` are lacking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `background-position: center center;`?

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. And thank you nmagerko for the units. I did forget those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the [specs concerning Background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp), especially the background-position property.

Comment: Very good idea. I took a look there, and I have a better understanding of the type of CSS elements that I can add to background. Thank you!