# Centering a background image with a gradient inline

Tags: css, background, gradient, transparent, background-position

My current css is

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 0%, rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 100%),
url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(47,163,216,0.85)), color-stop(100%,rgba(47,163,216,0.85))),
url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 0%,rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 100%),
url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 0%,rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 100%),
url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 0%,rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 100%),
url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 0%,rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 100%),
url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d92fa3d8', endColorstr='#d92fa3d8',GradientType=0 ),
url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg); /* IE6-9 */
background-position:center;
```

The problem is that the `background-position` isn't formatting the background image to center. Possibly something like `background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 0%,rgba(47,163,216,0.85) 100%),
    url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg) center;`?
Hope you can help!

Comment: As far as I can see it seem to center, perhaps you could provide the html you are running. You could also try to set the background-position: 50%; and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `background-position: center center;`?
This solution worked here: [Background Image won't center in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863169/background-image-wont-center-in-ie-9)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I just answered my own question. The solution was `url(http://i.imgur.com/HS5coix.jpg)50%;`. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for all the help!